# Values not getting displayed in logs for Powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am executing the below code in Azure Powershell task in Azure Devops:

```
$secret="<<SecretValue>>"
$AppId="<<ClientId>>"
$tenantid="<<TenantId>>"

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AppId, (ConvertTo-SecureString $secret –ASPlainText –Force))
Connect-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantId

$KeyVaultSecret= (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -vaultName '<<KVName>>' -name '<<SecretName>>').SecretValueText
write-host " Value: $KeyVaultSecret"
```

After job execution, the value is not getting displayed in job executions but the same code when executed via local system powershell displays the value.

Devops output:

[image]

Local System output:

[image]

Any reason why the value is not coming in Azure Devops?

Comment: Hi @Nandan, how are things going? Have you tried to run the pipeline on a self-hosted agent installed on your local system to execute the same PowerShell script? Please have a try. Any update, feel free to tell us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per default in Azure DevOps Pipelines, secrets in the output feed are attempted to be removed according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) (the "important" note section).

That could be the reason for this not showing in the output.

There is also another way of getting secrets from KeyVault through Variable Groups. [Here is the documentation for how to set that up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables).

Comment: Hey @jwweiler,
The issue I there is much more code involved as below
if ($KeyVaultSecret)
{
write-host "true"
}
else
{
write-host "False"
}

Ideally I am validating whether there is any secret already present in key vault and not actually want to display the value.
And internally also every time , the code is going into else condition ( even if I am not displaying the condition) in Azure Devops but is going into true condition in normal local execution

Comment: If the business logic depends on the value of the secret, this might be difficult to accomplish if the value can't be read properly in DevOps. However, I tested some things out in PowerShell in the Azure portal, and there, it is possible to retrieve the value by `$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '<keyvault name>' -Name '<secretname>'` and then `if($secret.SecretValue -eq "this or that") { ... }`. But of course, it depends on what you need to accomplish with the secret to go further from there. I do think it should be possible if converting to plain text can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a correct behavior. Azure DevOps has its own security strategy aims to protect your secrets and sensitive information.

If Azure DevOps allows the actual values of secrets can be printed in the console logs from key vault, any people who have the access to view the pipeline logs can get the secrets. Obviously, this will bring your secrets to the risk of being easily leaked.

When you directly execute the script on your local system, the security strategy for Azure DevOps is not applied to your local system, and also may not have any other security strategy for Azure is applied to your local system, so you can print the secret value to the output logs.

You can try to install a self-hosted agent on your system to run the script in pipeline on Azure DevOps. If the secret value still is hidden, as I mentioned above, it is the security strategy for Azure DevOps.

Comment: The issue I there is much more code involved as below if ($KeyVaultSecret) { write-host "true" } else { write-host "False" } Ideally I am validating whether there is any secret already present in key vault and not actually want to display the value. And internally also every time , the code is going into else condition ( even if I am not displaying the condition) in Azure Devops but is going into true condition in normal local execution

Comment: Hi @Nandan, Have you tried to run the pipeline on a self-hosted agent installed on your local system to execute the same PowerShell script? Does the secret value still not display? If it still does not display, I think the root reason is most likely related to the security policy for Azure DevOps.